# Does the instance variable travel from #new through form_for to #create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In the standard way to create a new blog post:

```
def new
  @post = Post.new(post_attr: value)
end

<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field %>
<% end %>
```

When submitting the form will invoker `Posts#create`

```
def create
   @post = Post.new(post_params)
   @post.save
end
```

Will the `@post` that is saved still have `post_attr`?

Is there a Rails-way to make `post_attr` travel through and be saved? In my real application, `post_attr` is the parent_id of post (I'm using nested routes).

Comment: Either your question is unclear or you have a big misconception. A controller is executed *before* the view is rendered.

Comment: Yes, the controller `#new` is executed before, resulting in `@post` having the `post_attr`. However, when I submit the form, we're now at `#create`. My question is whether `@post` at `#create` still have `post_attr` or it's an entirely different object?

Comment: Aha, you better show us what you're really trying to do. But in any case, it's definitely a brand new object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I submit the form, will @post still have post_attr?

No.

The `create` action typically sets up an instance like so:

```
@post = Post.new(params[:post])
```

The attributes are set in the `params` hash, which is populated from the data contained in the request posted by the client. If you do not include a field in the posted data, it will not appear in `params`.

One way to "pass through" attributes is to use a hidden field:

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :post_attrs %>
  <%= f.text_field %>
<% end %>
```

The posted values will have to be serialized like any other field on a form, so you can't use arbitrary method calls here.

Comment: I did implement the `hidden_field` but wondered if there's a better way. I'll let others answer then choose yours as the correct response. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@post at #create is a new object with the attributes that you sended from the view.

As long as you didn't make any changes in the view to the fields this attributes will be the same as where rendered.

Answer (score 0):

**ActiveRecord**

The [`@instance variable`](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/) does *not* traverse the different actions (by its nature, it's an *instance* variable):

> Ruby - What can objects have? Objects can have class and
>   instance variables. This means that a class can have instance
>   variables. Let’s reopen our Polygon class and add an instance
>   variable:

--

**New**

The way Rails persists the data between the actions is to populate the `ActiveRecord` object. When you call the **`new`** action, Rails creates a new object using the `Model.new` method. This essentially creates an empty object, which you are able to then pass to the `form_for` helper.

Once the `form_for` helper has the object, it renders the required `fields`. As far as rails is concerned, the `@instance variable` now ceases to exist.

--

**Create**

When you pass the data to the `create` method, what you're doing is sending `data` through the `params` hash. This means that when Rails calls the `create` method - it will have access to the data through that variable (not the instance var)

This is why you have to define another variable when you're in the `create` method:

```
def create
   @model = Model.new(model_params)
end
```

The difference is now you have the data from the `params` hash - you can use it to populate the `ActiveRecord object` & save it accordingly.